# Select minimum number from column which not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

```
I have in my column (id) values  
                               4
                               5
                               10
```

I want to choose minimum nubmer which not exists. Example value 1 then 2 then 3 and then 6.....

i'm trying this code

```
IF not EXISTS(SELECT min(id) from table1) select...
```

Comment: What is the maximum number? According to your example data, is it 10?

Comment: What is the desired result at all, `1` or `6`?

Comment: I dont really care about maximum number i want to select always minimum which not exists. If maximum number is needed then lets say that is 10

Comment: desire result is 1

Comment: Sorry i was mean select

Comment: According to your example you are expecting the minimum number is 3. Am I right?

Comment: I expect 1, next minimum will be 2 and next 3 and next 6

Answer (score 0):

You can find the first row where there does not exist a row with Id + 1.

Try this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 t1.Id+1 as ID
 FROM table t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table t2 WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id + 1)
ORDER BY t1.Id;
```

Check this..
<kbd>[**Online Demo HERE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/515929)</kbd>

Comment: Also when goes minimum value 0, i want to take next minimum value which is 6. This code selects -1

Comment: @user6615498 Please check the online demo I have provided, I think you will find your desired result through this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a numbers table](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) in your database, then it's easy:

```
SELECT MIN(Numbers.n) As MinMissingId
FROM [Numbers] 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t WHERE Numbers.n = t.ID
)
```

Here's a small script that creates the table copied from Aaron's article:

```
SELECT TOP (1000000) n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers(n)
-- WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
;
```

Comment: @user6615498: where? Btw, are you really using sql-server 2000?

Comment: Should i use both of code or just the first?Yes i'm using sql 2000

Comment: @user6615498: if you don't have a numbers-table yet you have to create one. The second query will do this, but i'm not sure if it works in sql-server 2000. Google for number-table sql-server2000. Here is one example: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11508/609

Comment: What if i will say that minimum id=0 select next number which not exists?

Comment: `...FROM [Numbers] WHERE n >= 0`. But if the table contains only  positive numbers you have this by default