# Select first missing id above 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have in my columns (ID) values

```
                           5
                           6
                           9
```

I want to select first missing IDfrom above 0. My desire select value will be 1.(if 1  exists then it will selects 2 and so on...).
I'm using this code:

```
SELECT MIN(id) As MinMissingId FROM table1 where id>=0
```

But my result is first existing ID and not missing

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of the other question because of the desire to get "1" if the first missing value is higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the next unused id starting with 1, works in all cases, e.g. table is empty or there's no gap:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT id FROM tab
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 0
 )
SELECT MIN(id) + 1
FROM cte
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
   SELECT * 
   FROM tab 
   WHERE tab.id = cte.id + 1
 )
```

Comment: Where i should put my table name? EX Table1

Comment: Well, this should be obvious, you put it instead of `tab`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by building on the answer in your related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521744/select-minimum-number-from-column-which-not-exist).

```
select (case when min(id) > 0 then 1 else min(id) + 1 end)
from table1 t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t2
                  where t2.id = t.id + 1
                 );
```

The idea is to find the first id that is missing.  If it is bigger

Comment: Where should i use my table? EX table1